# Correctly get size from Canvas UI element on Unity

Tags: unity

Normally when anchors are on the same position, we can use `.sizeDelta` or `.rect.width/height` from `RectTransform`, but if the anchor are stretched, both of them returns negative values:

[image: normal inspector]
[image: debug inspector]

Which in reality is not 5 in size at all:
[image: real button size on the canvas]

There are already `SetSizeWithCurrentAnchor` but how to get other's `RectTransform`'s absolute size?

Comment: What exactly does `.rect` equal?

Comment: Also, what does that screenshot show? I don’t see the RectTransform tool’s four blue handles which would show how big it is.

Comment: `.rect.width` shows -900, `.rect.height` shows -5, it doesn't show because i'm using panning tool instead of resize tool, but the real size is really should be as big as the picture above (not -5, not -900, about 180 x 150-ish)

Comment: i updated the last picture @EdMarty

Comment: Are any of the parent RectTransforms scaled or anything weird? Or do they all have expected values?

Comment: parent and grandparent are scaled

Answer (score 1):

RectTransform does not take any scaling (of itself or any parents) into account when performing layout or determining what the reported rect is. Try doing all UI layout with no scaling, setting only the RectTransform’s anchored position, size delta and anchors for position, and only relying on the CanvasScaler in the root Canvas to set the size on screen that you want.

If that doesn’t solve your problem, try starting from scratch and building just a visual copy without doing any scaling, and find the differences.